# How can I open a kitchen cabinet door where the child lock is keeping it closed?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, child-safety

We have recently moved into a new house and our kitchen cabinet doors appear to have child locks fitted.

One of the cabinets has suddenly locked shut, and we cannot get it open.

These images show what the child locks in one of the doors which is opening/closing normally.

Any suggestions as to how we can get the cupboard opened?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should always put photos inline as part of the question, not links to off-site hosting that can (read: will) bitrot.

Comment: For what it's worth, as a locksmith I Really Like the magnetic childproofing locks. They hold pretty securely and operate pretty easily, and unlike something the kid can see and try to manipulate, magnetic operation through a solid surface is a concept that toddlers have trouble grasping. Plus you can easily stick the "key" to a surface that's within your easy reach but out of the kid's, using its own magnet; mine hangs from the curtain rod over the kitchen sink. (Not that I have kids, but I do have cats, and occasionally have young visitors.) These used to be my standard baby-shower gift!

Answer (score 9):

Just found out that a magnet will unlock them! Used a fridge magnet and that did the trick.

The locks were something like
[image]

[these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/BABYGO-Magnetic-Cupboard-Drilling-Toddlers/dp/B07PNVC563/ref=sr_1_6?keywords=Baby%20Safety%20Locks&qid=1649667525&sr=8-6).

Comment: If you did not remove them yet (or do not need to use them), you should be able to "disable" the lock by flipping the hook latch up. Then you won't need the magnet each time.